# How to implement signature pad in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to get signature pad to show up in my wordpress page.

I go to https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad and install the script. But nothing renders in wordpress. is there a specific way to make js work in wordpress?

Here is a js fiddle link of it: https://jsfiddle.net/szimek/jq9cyzuc/

*Ive added the following to header, and the html to the body (nothing happens) :

placed the following html

```
<div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
<div class="signature-pad--body">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
<div class="signature-pad--footer">
  <div class="description">Sign above</div>

  <div class="signature-pad--actions">
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
      <button type="button" class="button" data-action="change-color">Change color</button>
      <button type="button" class="button" data-action="undo">Undo</button>

    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-png">Save as PNG</button>
      <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-jpg">Save as JPG</button>
      <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-svg">Save as SVG</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Post the implementation snippets you tried.

Comment: Are you sure that HTML is rendering in the WP template? Is the script loading?

Comment: The html renders. I see the script on the "inspect html" but i dont see it take effect. Ive placed it on both the footer & header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created signature code, it's working fine. Take a look at demo.

```html
<div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
    <div class="signature-pad--body">
      <canvas width="664" height="235" style="touch-action: none;"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="signature-pad--footer">
      <div class="description">Sign above</div>

      <div class="signature-pad--actions">
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
          <button type="button" class="button" data-action="change-color">Change color</button>
          <button type="button" class="button" data-action="undo">Undo</button>

        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-png">Save as PNG</button>
          <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-jpg">Save as JPG</button>
          <button type="button" class="button save" data-action="save-svg">Save as SVG</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<script src="https://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/js/signature_pad.js"></script>
<script src="https://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/js/app.js"></script>
```